# How to run a list of a class in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on asp.net core 2.0, in an mvc project. I have a class called `Compra` with a list of `Combos`. My question is, how can I list all combos and show them to the user?

My code for the class "Compra" is this:

```
public class Compra
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    List<Combo> Compras = new List<Combo>()
}
```

The view that I want to show to the user is a cshtml, I want it to be displayed like this if possible:

### Compra

#### Selected Combos

1. Element 1
2. Element 2
3. Element 3
4. Element 4
5. Element 5

Thanks in advance, David.

Comment: Could you show the code that you have attempted for the view?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Example how you can do..

```
     // class
     public class Compra
      {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        List<Combo> compras = new List<Combo>();
      }
     public class Combo
      {
        public int id{ get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
      } 

    // view
    @model Compra

      <ol>
        @foreach (var item in Model.compras)
         {
          <li>
              @item.Name
          </li>
         }
     </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Assuming that `Combo` class has `Title` as one of its property.

```
@model Compra

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page title"
}

<h2>Compra</h2>
<h3>Selected Combos</h3>

@foreach (var combo in Model.Compras){
    <ol>
        <li> @combo.Title </li>
    </ol>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using View-bag instead of using model

View Page .cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Compra";
}
<h2>Compra</h2>
<h3>Selected Combos</h3>
@if (ViewBag.compra != null)
{
    <ol>
        @foreach (var compra in ViewBag.compra.ComboList)
        {
            <li>
                @compra.NAME
            </li>
        }
    </ol>
}
```

Controller - Action Method
--Bind Compra Class

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Compra compra = new Compra();
            compra.ID = "1";
            compra.ComboList.Add(new Combo { ID = "1", NAME = "Element 1" });
            compra.ComboList.Add(new Combo { ID = "2", NAME = "Element 2" });
            compra.ComboList.Add(new Combo { ID = "3", NAME = "Element 3" });
            compra.ComboList.Add(new Combo { ID = "3", NAME = "Element 4" });
            compra.ComboList.Add(new Combo { ID = "3", NAME = "Element 5" });
            ViewBag.compra = compra;

            return View();
        }
```

Here your classes structure

```
public class Compra
    {
        public Compra()
        {
            ComboList = new List<Combo>();
        }
        public string ID { set; get; }
        public List<Combo> ComboList { set; get; }
    }

    public class Combo
    {
        public string ID { set; get; }
        public string NAME { set; get; }
    }
```

---

[image: Output]